# Can I run or execute dbt model based on output from a SQL statement?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Background: I have few models which are materialized as 'Table'. This tables are populated with wipe(Truncate) and Load. Now I want to protect my existing data in the Table if the query used to populate data is returning empty result set. How can I make sure an empty result set is not replacing my existing data in table.

My table lies in Snowflake and using dbt to model the output table.

Nutshell: Commit the transaction only when SQL statement used is returning Not empty result set.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using dbt `ref()` function, which allows us to reference one model within another?
https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/ref

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading data in a way that is not controlled via dbt and then you are using this table - this is called a source. You can read more about this in [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/using-sources).

dbt does not control what you load into a source, everything else that is the T in the ELT is controlled where you reference a model via ref() function. A great example if you have a source that changes and you load it into a table and make sure that incoming data does not "drop" already recorded data is "incremental" materialization. I suggest you read more in [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models#about-incremental-models).

Thinking incremental takes time and practise, also it is recommended every now and then to do a `--full-refresh`.

You can have pre-hooks and post-hooks that can check your sources with clever macros and add dbt tests. We would really need a little bit more context of what you have and what you wish to achieve to suggest a real response.